# PCA plot, dimensions plot

Tags: r, pca

I have found good [tutorial about PCA](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/fviz-pca-quick-principal-component-analysis-data-visualization-r-software-and-data-mining) 
One question is not clear me currently. I want to know, how is it possible to visualize not only `Dim1` vs `Dim2` results, but actually all possible pairs of dimensions (for example `Dim3` vs `Dim4`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualize the other dimensions by changing the `axes(1,2)` argument to e.g. `axes(3,4)`:

```
fviz_pca_ind(X, axes = c(3, 4), geom = c("point", "text"),
   label = "all", invisible = "none", labelsize = 4) 
# (...)
```

Side note: The first couple of principal components often contain almost all variation in the dataset. The last principal components are generally very uninteresting, because the variation in the dataset has been "summarized" by the preceding principal components, and therefore only contains residue information (noise).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have also the cases, where I have from PC1 till PC4 similar values (probably 30 - 20 % of variance). So it is interesting for me to see also 3 and 4 components. Thanks again